# How to create Excel list from row title including COUNTIF statement?

Tags: excel, list, indexing, ms-office, tally

I have created a spreadsheet with the tally function `=COUNTIF(E$2:H$41," * "&$A85&" * ")`, which is working, but now I would like to add an additional column that lists what groups those tallies occur.

For example, say `" * "&$A85&" * "` is searching for the word Apple in `E$2:H$41` and it was found in `E17`. I would want the title of that row to show. For this case Fruit from cell `A17`. If there were other rows in which Apple was found, say red, I would like those listed as well.

I have tried using the INDEX command but cannot get the formula to work that way.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is still only pulling one title. I haven't gotten this to work yet but could we use something like `=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$4:$H$41,SMALL(IF($A$4:$A$41=$A$86,ROW($A$4:$A$41)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$4:$H$41,SMALL(IF($A$4:$A$41=$A$86,ROW($A$4:$A$41)),ROW(1:1)),2))`?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say which column your `title` is in, but if were in column `D` then the formula below should work. if it's in column A then change the start to `=INDEX(A2:A41`.

`=INDEX(A2:A41,MATCH(1,(ISNUMBER(FIND($A85,E2:E41)))+(ISNUMBER(FIND($A85,F2:F41)))+(ISNUMBER(FIND($A85,G2:G41)))+(ISNUMBER(FIND($A85,H2:H41))),0))`

It's an array formula so you need to confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

It's an index formula that indexes `D2:D41` and then the match has a look at the 4 columns E, F, G, and H with `OR` (confusingly the `+` sign denotes or).

Because you wanted to search within the cell using *, I used `ISNUMBER(FIND($A85,G2:G41))` which returns the character number if it finds the text.

**To return more than 1 title**

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$41,SMALL(IF((ISNUMBER(FIND($A$85,$E$2:$E$41)))+(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$85,$F$2:$F$41)))+(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$85,$G$2:$G$41)))+(ISNUMBER(FIND($A$85,$H$2:$H$41))),ROW($A$2:$A$41)-1),ROW(1:1)),1),"")`

It's also an array formula so don't forget to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to add the curly brackets.

This formula in a single cell will not return multiple results so you need to drag/copy the formula down enough cells to accommodate as many results as you think will be returned.

each formula will be the same except for the part at the end `ROW(1:1:)` which will change to `ROW(2:2:)`, `ROW(3:3:)`.

I have placed the formula in cells `B85` and `B86` and below but I would advise against using this formula in an area of a sheet if you are going to insert and delete rows above as this sometimes breaks the `ROW(1:1:)` references.  I normally put a formula like this on a different sheet from the source data.

[image: multiple results]

Comment: The title would be found in the A column. Thank you for your help. The formula is not working though and is returning a #N/A in the cell.

Comment: I forgot to put an iferror at the start so it will show #N/A if nothing is found from what you have entered in cell A85. It also shows #N/A if you don't use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER when exiting the formula bar.  If you use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER  then {} will surround the formula.

Comment: The #N/A is showing in error though because there is an occurrence of the name in the search columns specified.

Comment: And you definitely pressed CTRL+SHIT+ENTER when you entered the formula so that when you highlight the cell the formula has curly brackets {}?

Comment: The CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER solved some of the problem but now the command is only listing one title where the name occurs, not multiple titles.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it would just return 1 title. It can be done so I'll update me answer shortly.